# Scala Connect Four Moving Between Rows

Tags: scala

I am trying to make a connect four game in scala.  Currently i have it so it prints the board everytime and switches between players asking them to enter which column they want.  The problem is I dont know how to change the rows.  All 64 moves stay in row 7 (the 1st row).  I was thinking of somehow doing a check that will check if there is already an X or O in the spot the user wants to play and just bump up the row.  Would i use a if else for this? So if x or o is there move up a row else make move.

```
// Initialize the grid 
val table = Array.fill(9,8)('.') 
var i = 0; 
while(i < 8){ 
table(8)(i) = (i+'0').toChar 
i = i+1;
}

/* printGrid: Print out the grid provided */
def printGrid(table: Array[Array[Char]]) { 
table.foreach( x => println(x.mkString(" "))) 
}

var allowedMoves = 64 
var spotsLeft = 8

//Player One
def player1(){
printGrid(table) 
println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
val move = readInt
table(7)(move) = ('X')
}

//Player Two
def player2(){
printGrid(table) 
println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
val move = readInt
table(7)(move) = ('O')

for (turn <- 1 to 32) { 
  player 1
  player 2
}
```

Comment: You could use `table.map(_.apply(move) == '.').indexOf(false) - 1` to find the index of the last occurrence of the dot, assuming the dot is your "empty entry" symbol. (There's probably a more readable alternative though) I suggest adding more abstractions to the code: Why not make a class `Table`, holding a sequence of `Row`? Also, I'd consider making the implementation immutable, or at least thinking hard about whether mutability makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: I've gotten the code to move to the second row using if and else:        //Player One
def player1(){
 printGrid(table) 
println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
val move = readInt
if (table(7)(move) !='.'){
table(6)(move) = 'X'
}
else
table(7)(move) = 'X'


}

//Player Two
def player2(){
 printGrid(table) 
println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
val move = readInt
if (table(7)(move) !='.')
table(6)(move) = 'O'
else
table(7)(move) = 'O'
}      but now i am not sure how to advance it anymore

Comment: I don't think conditionals is the right choice here. The next step would be to check `if(table(6) != '.')`, then `if(table(5)!='.'`, and so on. You can already see that this leads to a lot of duplication and won't lead to a result if the table can be arbitrary large. You'd have to find the `index` of the first empty entry in your column, as I mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you're still baffled by my comments, but let me try to give you a more in-depth explanation here.

The code in question is:

```
//Player One
def player1(){
  printGrid(table) 
  println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
  val move = readInt
  table(7)(move) = ('X')
}

//Player Two
def player2(){
  printGrid(table) 
  println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
  val move = readInt
  table(7)(move) = ('O')
}

for (turn <- 1 to 32) { 
  player1
  player2
}
```

where the players take turns. But before going straight to the answer, let us refactor this code a bit by removing the duplication we have here. `player1` and `player2` are almost the same implementation. So let us pass the distinct parts as a parameter. The distinct part is the **name of the player** and the **symbol that represents this player in the table**. So let us define a class `Player`:

```
case class Player(name: String, symbol: Char)
```

and contract the two functions into one:

```
def player(player: Player): Unit ={
  printGrid(table)
  println(s"${player.name} it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
  val move = readInt
  table(7)(move) = player.symbol
}

for (turn <- 1 to 32) {
  player(Player("Player 1", 'X'))
  player(Player("Player 2", 'O'))
}
```

Now, we don't have to do everything twice, but the problem is still the same.

Okay, let's say, we are going to use conditionals: If `table(7)(move)` is occupied, then we choose `table(6)(move)`. However, if this is also occupied, we choose `table(5)(move)`. This goes on, until we find the column is completely full, in which case we may for example want to throw an exception. In code, this would look as follows:

```
def player(player: Player): Unit = {
  printGrid(table)
  println(s"${player.name} it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
  val move = readInt
  if (table(7)(move) != '.') {
    if (table(6)(move) != '.') {
      if (table(5)(move) != '.') {
        if (table(4)(move) != '.') {
          if (table(3)(move) != '.') {
            if (table(2)(move) != '.') {
              if (table(1)(move) != '.') {
                if (table(0)(move) != '.') {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Column $move is already full")
                } else table(0)(move) = player.symbol
              } else table(1)(move) = player.symbol
            } else table(2)(move) = player.symbol
          } else table(3)(move) = player.symbol
        } else table(4)(move) = player.symbol
      } else table(5)(move) = player.symbol
    } else table(6)(move) = player.symbol
  } else table(7)(move) = player.symbol
}
```

Let's run the code and... **yay, it works!**. But it is terrible code. There is an awful lot of duplication and we couldn't easily make the table bigger.

Okay, what problem do we really want to solve? We want to find the highest index of the row that has a free space at `move`, i.e., contains a `'.'` at `move`.

How could we find this index? There exists a function `indexOf` that takes an argument `x` and returns the index of the first occurrence of `x` in the array. But our array `table` is a two-dimensional array, and we care only about the value at `move` in each inner array. Fortunately, every collection in Scala provides a function `map` to map each element, so we could do: `table map (_(move))`.

Say that we receive the following array: `. . O X O O 2`, so the index of the last occurrence of `.` is 1. But `indexOf` will return the first index, so `indexOf('.')` would return 0. We could reverse the array, because finding the first index in the reversed array is equivalent to finding the last index in the array, but this is a bit tricky, as we also need to inverse the index, because the the index in the reversed array is generally not the same as the index in the original array.

Let's apply a little trick: Instead of finding the last index of `.`, let's find the index of the first element that is not `.` and subtract one. But the function `indexOf` does not allow us to pass a `not x`. However, we can solve this problem by modifying our map function slightly: Instead of `table map (_(move))`, let's map to `table map (_(move) == '.')`. Now, we need to find the index of the first `false` value and subtract one.

The whole solution would look as follows:

```
def player(player: Player): Unit = {
  printGrid(table)
  println(s"${player.name} it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
  val move = readInt
  val freeRows = table map (_(move) == '.')
  val indexOfLastFreeRow = (freeRows indexOf false) - 1
  if (indexOfLastFreeRow == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Column $move is already full")
  else table(indexOfLastFreeRow)(move) = player.symbol
}

for (turn <- 1 to 32) {
  player(Player("Player 1", 'X'))
  player(Player("Player 2", 'O'))
}

case class Player(name: String, symbol: Char)
```

I hope this answer helps. As a final note: I would still not work with plain arrays, but instead define a class `Table` and `Column` and let them provide the functionality to add elements, and an appropriate `toString` to print the table.

```
case class Table(columns: List[Column]) {
  override def toString = (for (i <- 0 until columns.head.values.length) yield {
    columns map (_.values(i).toString) reduceLeft (_ + " " + _)
  }) reduceLeft (_ + System.lineSeparator + _)

  def add(entry: Char, columnIndex: Int): Table = {
    val (prefix, column :: suffix) = columns.splitAt(columnIndex)
    Table(prefix ++ (column.add(entry) :: suffix))
  }
}
object Table {
  val EmptyEntry = '.'

  def empty(numberOfColumns: Int, numberOfRows: Int): Table =
    Table(List.fill(numberOfColumns)(Column.empty(numberOfRows)))
}

case class Column(values: List[Char]) {

  def isFull: Boolean = !values.contains(Table.EmptyEntry)

  def add(entry: Char): Column = {
    if (isFull) this
    else {
      val (empty, filled) = values.partition(_ == Table.EmptyEntry)
      Column(empty.dropRight(1) ++ (entry :: filled))
    }
  }
}
object Column {
  def empty(numberOfRows: Int): Column =
    Column(List.fill(numberOfRows)(Table.EmptyEntry))
}
```